# upgrade wordpress plugin via ftp

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, ftp

I am currently using the layerslider plugin on my website but received an error, I was told it needs to be updated. I have got the updated version in a zip file from the developer, he told me to do the following steps below. Could you please explain in more detail, I know how to overwrite files, but not sure about replacing old files? Thanks John

Just overwrite the latest files through FTP and replace the old files. Just go to wp-content/plugins/ folder and you can find the layerslider folder.

Comment: Overwrite and replace is the same thing. You could also delete the old plugin and upload the new one.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. The way it was explained was a bit confusing.

Comment: My pleasure - cheers ;)